# How to edit watchdog.conf file to enable watchdog

Tags: linux, watchdog

I am new to watchdog concept. I have to enable watchdog in my linux system. If my PC gets hang, I wanna restart my PC using this watchdog.

For this,I have enabled the following lines in watchdog.conf file.,

max-load-1              = 2

watchdog-device         = /dev/watchdog

watchdog-timeout        = 15

interval                = 1

sigterm-delay           = 5

realtime                = yes

priority                = 1

Also I have checked if the watchdog is running by using the following command,

**service watchdog status**

My pc did not got restart ,even if my PC load goes to 3. Am I need to modify the watchdog.conf file?

Anyone could you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Kill the watchdog service and see if the machine restarts.

Comment: No. It is also not working